# Removing Oracle killed session

Tags: oracle, session, kill, database-administration

I killed a session

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '123,456' IMMEDIATE;
```

But it remains in `v$session` for 5 days, although an attached process is absent in `v$processes`.

```
SELECT
    s.username,
    s.osuser,
    s.sid,
    s.serial#,
    p.spid
  FROM v$session s, v$process p
 WHERE s.sid = '123'
   AND p.addr (+)= s.paddr;
```

I've also checked all Linux processes related to Oracle and found no zombies: all present processes are consistent to alive sessions.

**EDIT:** *This happens not for all the killed sessions. It seems that PMON is active, because the most of the killed sessions are cleaned from the list in a reasonable time (often it takes a second).*

What can be done to eliminate long-playing killed session from the list?

Comment: In worst case you have to restart the database.

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit, I guess I will have. But before that I'd like to understand why it has happened and is there a less brutal way to make the cleanup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These should be cleaned up by PMON automatically, but sometimes you need to 'wake it up' in the case of stuck processes.

To wake up PMON, first obtain the PID using

```
SELECT pid FROM v$process
WHERE addr = 
(
    SELECT paddr FROM v$bgprocess
    WHERE name = 'PMON'
);
```

If the PID is 6 then send a wakeup call using:

> ORADEBUG WAKEUP 6

and you might have to repeat that command a few times until the runaway session is cleared.

Comment: Apparently, PMON is active, because other sessions, being killed by the command, presently almost immediately disappear from the list. Nevertheless, the session, about which the question was asked, remains in the KILLED status for more than 10 days.

Comment: Did you try the wakeup? It's a way of forcing PMON to clean up, even though it's active for normal closed or abended sessions.

Comment: Yes, I connected SYS as SYSDBA. Executed ORADEBUG WAKEUP 2 (that's current pid of PMON). Got response `Statement processed`. The session is still there in status KILLED.

Comment: Did you kill the actual process from the OS?  (spid from v$process) - it might be a bit late now to find the pid, but in future if pmon does not clear KILLED status quickly, then kill the process, and run the wakeup up to 3 times.  Make sure first the process is not rolling back otherwise on restart of the database it will roll back and you will wonder why restart is taking so long.

Answer (score 0):

A session may remain in the killed status if it depends on another session that has not been terminated.

The connection can be viewed by request:

```
select taddr, status, sid, serial#, LAST_CALL_ET from v$session
where taddr in
  ( select taddr from v$session where status='KILLED' )
order by 1,2 desc ,3;
```

Information obtained from the note: "Killed Session Are Not Cleaned By PMON, Sessions are part of Distributed Transactions (Doc ID 1581551.1)"